# Recommendations for Debian VPN install scripts

Tags: debian, software-installation, openvpn

recommendations for debian  openVPN server install scripts? one that runs well with debian 9 and 10  .

old notes I found https://github.com/h1777/3proxy-http but it is a little deprecated and unmaintained. something similar would be perfect.

Comment: "vpn server install scripts" seems a little vague ... there's several types of vpn, some of which have several implementations

Comment: What kind of script did you want? OpenVPN worked fine for me on Debian 9 and 10 pretty much out of the box. I just needed to tweak the settings in `/etc/default/openvpn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @roaima  said openvpn now has an install script that works without errors on Debian 9 and 10.

Followed:
https://www.hostslim.eu/blog/how-to/how-to-install-openvpn-in-under-5-minutes/

most of the steps encountered were the same as in tutorial, which is helpful. In conclusion: openvpn-install.sh will work for install and client account creation.  But with caveat noted below.

Note: openvpn may still not work as a vpn even if install is completed without error and client can successfully initialize login to vpn.  That is the topic of another post.